# A data type like vector but sorted

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, types

Is there a data type like vector or queue where you can easily add items, but when they get added, they are automatically inserted in the right order?

Also is there an easy way to delete an item from a vector or queue if you know what it is, without having to actually search through and find it?

Comment: "inserted in the right order" According to...?

Comment: Like if they're integers, sorted.

Comment: [Well why not just say what you plan on using it for instead of conjuring up hypothetical situations](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a `set` and not a vector. It will be sorted according to the natural ordering (the `<` operator).  To remove an element by value call `erase`.

Alternately you can just use `sort` on a vector to sort the elements. If you need random access to the elements then you will want this approach; the sorted containers do not provide random access.

To find an element in a sorted vector you can use `binary_search`.

Answer (score 2):

I know no such container.

`std::sort` exists, in which you can specifiy the sorting function, but it is often even more efficient to actually insert items in the *right* place directly.

If you always do that, the only "problem" you have to solve is to add an item into an already sorted list, which can be done at worst in linear time.

Note that `std::vector<T>::insert()` takes an iterator as a parameter, to indicate where to do the insertion. You might want to write a `findPosition()` methods that returns such an iterator. Then, writing an `sorted_insert()` method is trivial and becomes something like:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator findPosition(int v);
void sorted_insert(std::vector<int>& vec, int v) { vec.insert(findPosition(v), v); }

void foo()
{
  std::vector<int> vec;
  sorted_insert(vec, 4);
}
```

Comment: Or you can just use `std::set`... (I feel a bit dumb right now)

Comment: I love the fact that two people also think I'm "a bit dumb" :D

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want `std::set` or `std::multi_set`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need and why do you need it.

No, in the standard lib, there's no "sorted" vector or queue. You have 2 options, if you want to use **only** the standard library:

- sort the container(vector or queue) on each insertion/deletion
- implement your own insert/delete, by implementing the [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Other option is to use map or set, if they'll be OK for your problem (as we don't know what it is)

The other option is to look for some 3rd party lib - I guess [boost](http://www.boost.org/) will have such container, but I don't really know that.

"Also is there an easy way to delete an item from a vector or queue if you know what it is"
- what do you mean by that? You have an iterator to it or ? Or its index? I'll edit my answer when you update (: